# Crashing at random intervals, possibly from heat or voltage?

Tags: linux, temperature, opensuse

My CPU is an AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 6000+

Its rating is 55 - 63 C with a Vcore voltage of 1.35 / 1.4. My system (OpenSuse latest version) crashes often at random intervals. Recently I thought it might be because my CPU is overheating.

The output of 'sensors' tells me my CPU is running at 62C with 1.5V at vcore.

Is this enough to cause a crash (keep in mind these are semi-idle conditions)

Comment: I made it all myself a couple years ago. However, the crashes only started happening recently.  Not sure about the CPU, I just bought it at a part store and it came with a heatsink. All AMD branding and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cooling solution is inadequate, [Prime95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime95) should provoke a crash fairly quickly.

**Edit**

Sorry, missed the OpenSUSE mention...try the [distributed.net client](http://www.distributed.net/Download_clients), it's what I used to use back in the day for torture testing on Linux.

Your temp sounds a bit high for idle [based on this](http://devforums.amd.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=319&threadid=108439&highlight_key=y).  Check the voltage settings in the BIOS, make sure you're not overvolting it, Vcore should be 1.3 or 1.35.

Comment: Do you know a linux variant (can't seem to find mprime either) of this?

Comment: So I went into BIOS and it said my vcore was at 1.5V and cpu temp was 64C. My motherboard was also 31C and my cpu fan was at 3054 RPM. This seems like a whole lot. Also, is it possible to actually step down the vcore voltage?

Comment: Its an M3N78-Pro board. http://www.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=DVvm9CU0G1bCC4gp&content=specifications

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see the Temps of the CPU in the BIOS Temp Utility? 
Normaly you get a more realistic Value there cause the CPU is on semi-Idle Mode what results in normal use of a PC.

Greetings,
mitsosc

Comment: BIOS said my vcore was 1.5V and cpu temp was 64C. Ouch